# Makefile with OpenMP: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I have a problem including parallel calculation with OpenMP in my makefile. The error I got is

**cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files**

Here is my makefile:

```
GSLFLAGS := pkg-config --cflags gsl
LIBGSL := pkg-config --libs gsl

CFLAGS = -c -C -O3 -openmp=parallel

lateral.o:lateral.cxx

    g++ -c lateral.cxx 

main.o:main.cxx 

    g++ -c main.cxx  $< ${GSLFLAGS} ${CFLAGS}

alg:main.o lateral.o

    g++ -o  $@ $^ ${LIBGSL}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO (but can't test right now) there's something wrong with this line:

```
CFLAGS = -c -C -O3 -openmp=parallel
```

I think `-openmp=parallel` should just be `-fopenmp`. First because that's the correct compile flag for OpenMP, second because what's after `-o` will be interpreted as the name of the output file. And as your error message says, you can't use `-c` and `-o` together.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
g++ -c main.cxx $< ${GSLFLAGS} ${CFLAGS}
```

Should read

```
g++ -c main.cxx ${GSLFLAGS} ${CFLAGS}
```

because, `$<` expands to the first prerequisite, `main.cxx`, giving `g++ -c main.cxx main.cxx`. To avoid that, you can even write generic rules like:

```
%.o: %.cxx
    g++ -c -o $@ ${GSLFLAGS} ${CFLAGS} $^
```

And you don't need special rules for `main.o` and `lateral.o`, the complete makefile would be:

```
GSLFLAGS := pkg-config --cflags gsl
LIBGSL := pkg-config --libs gsl

all: alg

%.o: %.cxx
    g++ -c -o $@ ${GSLFLAGS} ${CFLAGS} $^

alg: main.o lateral.o
    g++ -o  $@ $^ ${LIBGSL}
```

You can find a detailed explanation of the syntax above [here](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) or a much more detailed documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefiles).

**Edit**:

Sorry I missed the C flags, there is also an error there:

```
CFLAGS = -c -C -O3 -openmp=parallel
```

Your should remove the `-c` since you are already using it in the rule, which is what `gcc` is complaining about.

Comment: Hi, thanks but removing $< I get this error                               **GCC does not support -C or -CC without -E**